Movie about young Australians marooned on island with a creep
I am looking to watch a movie I haven't seen in several years, but I cannot remember its title.
What I can tell you is that the premise has a group of young Australians, (early 20s, I believe), marooned on an island. There, they come across a creepy older man. While they are out scouting, the creepy fellow sodomizes a girl called Emily, which a boy witnesses, so he tries to intervene, leading to a physical altercation with the creep.
Now, things that should be taken as a grain of salt: I THOUGHT it was based on Stephen King's work, but I seem to be unable to identify it as such. I also THOUGHT "Island" was in the title, but I may be mistaken.

Lost Things is the answer! It is about a group of friends who go to a beach, which is representative of Limbo of Christianity scripture.
